# Why has the overloaded Add been replaced with AddWithValue?

Tags: .net, sqlcommand

The overloaded method [SqlParameterCollection.Add(String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1.aspx) has been marked as deprecated since version 3.5 SP1 of the .NET Framework. You should use the [AddWithValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method that was introduced with version 2.0.

Is there a good reason why the Add(String, Object) has been replaced with a AddWithValue()? I'm fine with the change, but I am curious about why the change was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that it's because of the possibility for misuse described in the MSDN docs you referenced:

> Use caution when you are using this
>   overload of the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add method to
>   specify integer parameter values.
>   Because this overload takes a value of
>   type Object, you must convert the
>   integral value to an Object type when
>   the value is zero, as the following C#
>   example demonstrates.

```
parameters.Add("@pname", Convert.ToInt32(0));
```

> If you do not perform this conversion,
>   the compiler assumes that you are
>   trying to call the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add (string,
>   SqlDbType) overload.

In fact the docs you referenced for the new API say as much:

> The overload of Add that takes a
>   string and an object was deprecated
>   because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload
>   that takes a String and a SqlDbType
>   enumeration value where passing an
>   integer with the string could be
>   interpreted as being either the
>   parameter value or the corresponding
>   SqlDbType value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was due to ambiguity due to the value being passed via `Object`, and other overloads of `Add()`. I can recall having situations where I was unintentionally calling a different version of Add() because the value I was passing happened to be of a different, more specific data type.

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old post, but you should read:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Is says basically that `AddWithValue` could sometimes incorrectly infer the correct type. Use `Add` instead.